# matching a letter with a word

Tags: java, arrays

I've the below code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dummy {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String word="hi";
        String[] one={"a","b","c"};
        String[] two={"d","e","f"};
        String[] three={"g","h","i"};
        String[] four={"j","k","l"};
        String[] five={"m","n","o"};
        String[] six={"p","q","r","s"};
        String[] seven={"t","u","v"};
        String[] eight={"w","x","y","z"};

        for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<three.length;j++)
            {
                if(three[j].equals(word.charAt(i)))
                {
                    System.out.println("Matched");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("err");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here my concept is to match a letter from the string to the array created and here the output is all err(condition stating not matched). please let me know where am i going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing a single-character string (from your arrays) to a character. Make your arrays of `char`, not `String`. (And use `==` to compare them.)

Comment: Thank you verymuch, this is helpful, i want t know if there is a way i can get the array name. Like matched and array is three

Answer (score 1):

The element three[j] in for loop is String whereas word.charAt(i) is char.. so equals() against those will be always false.

You should either change it to

if(three[j].equals(String.valueOf(word.charAt(i))))

so that it compares string's actual context, or define arrays (one, two, three.. ) to be char array instead of string array so that you can simply use == for that.

Please check equals() for String, Object, and the others in JavaDoc, and probably you need to check hashCode() as well to fully understand what's equals() means in Java.

Answer (score 0):

charAt return a char not a string so it can't be "equals" to a String

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [String.indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) ?

```
for(int j=0;j<three.length;j++)
{
     if(word.indexOf(three[j]) == -1)
     {
          System.out.println("err");
     }
     else
     {
          System.out.println("Matched");
     }

}
```

This way you will enter in a single loop..

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < one.length; i++) {
    result.append(one[i]);
}
if (result.toString().equals(word)) {
    System.out.println("Matched");
} else {
    System.out.println("err");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just saying the obvious....sometimes it is helpful to see the actual code. Following is excerpt from java.lang.String

See bold condition in particular. it returns false if instanceof fails!

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (**anObject instanceof String**) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
        char v1[] = value;
        char v2[] = anotherString.value;
        int i = offset;
        int j = anotherString.offset;
        while (n-- != 0) {
            if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
```